# Bootstrap collapse not closed

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, bootstrap-4

When I click away the menu it opens but doesn't hide. I Tried to use different versions of bootstrap links but it doesn't work. For example I used

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

     <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
               <h4 class="panel-title">
                   <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThirteen">Other Countries<i class="indicator glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up  pull-right"></i>
                   </a>
               </h4>
         </div>
     <div id="collapseThirteen" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body c-d">
               <p><b>Annual Course Fee Details </b><a href="images/2019/feeinternational/South-Africa-Fee.pdf" target="blank">Click Here</a> </p>
              <p><b>Hostel Fee Per Year</b></p>
              <p>1100 USD</p>
              <br/>
              <p><b>Including Food, Accommodation, Swimming Pool, Laundry, 24*7 WiFi, 4 times meal, Gym, Sports & Cinema</b></p>
           </div>
      </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Accordion does close on clicking the toggle link. Are you expecting some other behavior?

Comment: Would you like it to close if you click anywhere but the menu? Like you open it, and it would disappear if you click somewhere outside the menu?

Comment: yes i want to open and close on click..............

Answer (score 0):

Include the Bootstrap.js file *after* jQuery, not before.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data-parent` attribute from the anchor tag.

Comment: Maybe this resource is modified src="js/bootstrap.min.js", try to remove that and use online version. Look at the console too, maybe it shows some error.

Comment: thanks its work i just remove internal bootstrap.min.js and used only online version.